# CameraX analysis resolution too low (640x480) but Camera2 can do better (720x1280)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

So I have an issue with a device (Alcatel 5033D 1) that's always giving me a resolution of 480x640 for CameraX analysis. This is the last version of the code in which I init it:

```
    private void initCameraAnalysis(Size resolution) {
        Log.d(TAG, "initCameraAnalysis: ");
        cameraAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(resolution)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setImageQueueDepth(0)
                .build();
        cameraAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                cameraExecutor,
                new QualityAnalyzer()
        );
    }
```

I just added this part to see if it would help, initially these calls weren't there and they actually don't help with this issue:

```
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setImageQueueDepth(0)
```

The resolution is passed when calling that method as follows, and so I'm requesting 720x1280 that's what I need (using portrait orientation):

```
initCameraAnalysis(new Size(720, 1280));
```

Now, this is a low end device and always fallback to 480x640 *but* I have another app made by a colleague that still uses Camera2 and that one can make 720x1280 with this same device without issue, so I know for sure the device is actually capable of doing 720x1280.

Moreover, I have added an ImageCapture use case and that one can do 720x1280 without issue too, but I need it to do 720x1280 during the analysis.

So I wonder if there'd be any way to force 720x1280 in the analysis use case despite the stubbornness of CameraX not taking it, even if it means using some Camera2 extension or whatever.

Otherwise is likely I'd have to rewrite the whole app using Camera2 instead, which seems like going backwards in time...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: new Size(1280, 720)) ?

Comment: @blackapps Sorry, I missed your comment. Thanks but 720, 1280 is the right thing to do in this case because I'm using portrait. See my answer to Orcum below. (In any case if you are curious, if I use 1280, 720 I get 640x480 instead too)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If you have seen it but just in case you did not I would like to point what stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration#specify-resolution):

> Express the resolution Size in the coordinate frame after rotating the supported sizes by the target rotation. For example, a device with portrait natural orientation in natural target rotation requesting a portrait image may specify 480x640, and the same device, rotated 90 degrees and targeting landscape orientation may specify 640x480.

Maybe also give it a shot with:

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
    .build()
```

Comment: I'm using portrait, so 720, 1280 is the right thing to do according to the docs. Moreover, I use the same size for ImageCapture and in that case it works as expected. It is as though the analysis use case couldn't deal with 720x1280 in that device, though with Camera2 it does...

Comment: That's indeed weird. One thing I would try though is using `720x1280` for only ImageAnalysis use case. I have had in the past a problem that Preview use case and ImageAnalysis use case could not use same resolution at the same time. So, maybe try with setting other use cases with resolution `480x640` and ImageAnalysis with `720x1280`. Of course this might not be desired for your case but at least you could diagnose the problem.

Comment: that doesn't help. What I was thinking was about perhaps going to a lower level somehow to tweak some Camera2 stuff, but I'm not that familiar with that TBH.